# May a Muslim learn how to perform telepathy?

Tags: halal-haram, metaphysical

I would like to know Islam's view on telepathy based on rulings by Scholars well-grounded in the Qur'an and the Sunnah as well as the Manhaj of the Sahaabah (RAA).

There is an oft-repeated incident related to telepathy about Caliph Omar (RAA) who shouted and warned another Companion (RAA) who was quite far away in Jihaad in another land. Unfortunately I do not recall the specific incidents nor can I find any reliable source for it.

The question specifically is: is a Muslim allowed to learn telepathy? Is there any such thing?

Comment: As long as it's not *shirk*, what would make you worry that it's not allowed?

Comment: If you can learn telepathy, please document it thoroughly. Scientists would have a field day if you can provide evidence of breaking the laws of physics and nature.

Comment: You are referring to this incident http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30412/the-hadith-regarding-ya-sariyya-al-jabal-is-it-authentic-or-daif-or-false

Answer (score 3):

There are two things called samira and basira, because Allah s.w.t is al Sami ual Basir, who listen everything and sees everything, so the person with a lot of faith and very pure, there is a hadith which says that Allah s.w.t ´s ear becames his ear, and Allah s.w.t ´s eye becames his eye, so he listen to things others cannot, and sees what others cannot. And is a bless, not a sin.

So other powers which Allah s.w.t lend us, like our technology what it is infime compared with his, because He lend us very little percent of his characteristics, like patience, strength, etc if we deserve it. so telepathy for me is the same, and can be also a prove of you're gaining level of illumination and being nearer to Allah s.w.t, but also can be the demon making you think you have that power so you think you are doing well in your way and you're not, so careful in those powers.

Illumination doesn't consist in obtaining more and more power, that comes together but it's not the objective, you being more generous, doing more charity, can be a proof of your good evolution as well. And you don't need telepathy for that. I think you can study those things if your intention is to help your religion or like hobby after doing your really strong work inside religion, and if you study in a halal way, good for your religion way, not going to sihr magic, studying shaitan books, I mean studying inside religion or inside science like psychology. But also in science you can believe later more in science that in religion. And think you're leaving a good deed, leaving a useful science or knowledge after your death, and it is not useful, how much technology has already the men, and continue being bad or disbelievers, and people with powers can even be more proud of them and seek those things like you, more than religion, we want people go to mosques not to power schools. I mean the first is the important, and if you have powers your ego can rise and Allah s.w.t don't like the arrogant.

Imagine thinking or saying I'm best than those because I have telepathy. you are not best by that, you can be best because of your taqwa fair of Allah s.w.t and love to Allah s.w.t. that is what Allah s.w.t is going to look when you are dead and your good deeds you left, not if you had telepathy, you must focus in that Allah s.w.t loves you more, and I think the idea is not have telepathy, is fasting more, praying more, memorizing smiling to your brothers, being educated, help others, give charity, at tariq the way up, memorizing the whole Quran that can give you the yannat firdaus the best paradise, the telepathy is only for this world the dunia, but by my experience if you memorize Quran or hear it very often and make dhikr repetition of verses things like that you can develop telepathy and do astral trips easily etc also studying yourself or how Allah s.w.t has created the heavens that gives you hasanats good points inshallah (there are things which most people ignore and decide to play all the time instead of study), that things can make you more conscious and when you are more conscious can make more things that before you couldn't.

Remember when you are prostrated praying is the nearest to Allah s.w.t because is the posture you are more conscious, so wanting to be more conscious is going nearer Allah s.w.t so it is good thing, telepathy can be prove of more consciousness some times its relative can be the demon. But you don't need telepathy to grow your consciousness, at least at some level, that's the thing, if you has excuse to learn it or not. I know if you are more and more thankful to Allah s.w.t of what you already have and don't use it for bad, Allah s.w.t can give you more and more things inshallah. Sometimes He doesn't give you because you are not prepared or has not the strength to hold it, if you has a weak body by example by drugs, how he can give you powers related with your body without harming you, first you will have to leave your addictions. And ask Allah s.w.t for helping you in that first.

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum and Welcome to Islam.SE, please consider formatting your answer to make it readable.

Comment: +1 for now. But you really need to backup your answer with references. especially if its permissible to learn it today.

Answer (score 0):

Telekinesis, ___kinesis, whatever kinesis, is NOT magic. There are ACTUAL BLACK MAGIC witchcraft spell-like psychic attacks. Now THAT is haram. That is what is considered "magic". Kinesis is science and manipulation of energy. Nothing more.

Comment: any references? [How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I can ansewer your last Question. " Is there any such thing? as Telepathy". The answer to this is yes. Telepathy can be preformed by black magic. I have experienced this, as I was a victim of black magic. This is not limited to just transferring thoughts from brain to brain, but you can also make people feel emotions you have and make them see visually what you imagine. The distance between two individual; how many individual and what information you are transferring from brain to brain in my experience is not a limiting factor in this kind of telepathy. Unfortunately this kind of telepathy is haram.

I do not know of how Caliph Omar (RAA) shouted and warned another Companion (RAA) from a far distance. And I don't think anyone knows this.